# How to completely destroy docker container from marathon UI?

Tags: docker, mesos, marathon

I have docker registry from where Mesos pull the containers.My problem is when i destroy the app from Marathon UI and again call the Marathon rest api to deploy the app with same version of app,  Mesos is not pulling image from the  Master Docker registry It's pulling the image somewhere from local registry or cache. I realized this thing because Mesos completes the task in seconds and if I change the version it takes good time to deploy.

Please let me know If anyone has solution(or confusion related to the question) for this because I read all the documents i didn't get any solution.

Thanks

Comment: If you provide full path to the registry, it shouldn't pull image from anywhere but your private docker registry. Is your issue that it's pulling incorrect image?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `forcePullImage` flag to `true` as mentioned in [here](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/native-docker.html). Force pull instructs `docker` binary to pull the image from the registry even if it is already downloaded on the slave. Please refer to the [corresponding documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/pull/) for how the `docker pull` command works.

Comment: Force pull instructs `docker` to pull the image from the registry even if it is already downloaded on the slave. This results in a `docker pull` invocation, please check the corresponding documentation on how this command works (https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/pull/)